# Communication between Rails and Ruby EventMachine Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, eventmachine, unix-socket

I have a rails app which needs to request data from a local running process running EventMachine. What is the best way of implementing this request/response?

Comment: You need the data sync (for a http response) or async (as worker)?

Comment: @tass I want rails to ask a process for some data and the process to respond with the data immediately like the interaction between a web server and a browser. The data would probably be in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I ended up using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it, but I'd try to use sockets for it.
EM - listen and recieve messages, return data, Rails - connect to EM and send a message and recieve data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the perfect answer, but I'm looking into the same problem and am going to try to use https://github.com/kwi/BrB.

Also, check out this blog post: http://www.tricksonrails.com/2010/04/introducing-brb-extremely-fast-interface-for-doing-distributed-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

Also check a new gem: [websocket-rails](https://github.com/DanKnox/websocket-rails)
offers plug and play websocket support for ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to have your backend talk HTTP. Your Rails app then just makes an HTTP request to your backend server. Return the data in JSON and use as needed in Rails.

At PostRank we created [Goliath](http://goliath.io) which we ran behind HAProxy to surface data for our Rails apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`IO.pipe`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-pipe) if you're under *nix system and you are performing a fork for `EM.run` loop.

Comment: All other answers to this questions propose to use cannon to kill flies.